# Extending F1 score to classification with uncertainty

Tags: classification, uncertainty, f1

I have a classifier that can return yes, no's and "maybe"s.

The maybe indicates that we don't have certainty in a prediction because the data point is is not sufficiently close to it's nearest neighbour (I'm using a nearest neighbour algorithm).

Is there a good way of adapting the F1-score to this?

You could extend to a three class classifier and use some of the extensions of f1 to multiclass classifiers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score#Extension_to_multi-class_classification, but this seems wrong because a maybe isn't wrong it's just not right.

I guess some of this stuff might come up in when you have drop out or non-response in studies.

Approaches:

- People suggested the Brier score. This applies when you have a  classifier that returns a probability of each class. This is not the case here. If my point is far from all other data points we cannot be certain of either yes or no.

Comment: Reopening the question as I believe it was closed retaliatorily. Also adding some more details. I am of course willing to provide clarification - but note that providing clarification until my approach fits a preferred solution and barking orders at me is not requesting clarification

Comment: It’s not clear how you would define a point as a “maybe”. Could you please explain that?

Comment: If a point is too far from any known point it is labelled as maybe.

Comment: How do you determine the distance at which you would consider a point to be a “maybe”?

Comment: This threshold is a distance that I'm trying to tune, hence the desire to have have a "standard score" of some description. One approach would be just to ascribe different costs to the errors in the confusion matrix average them - but this is rather arbitrary unlike f1's "standard" score.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a probability of class membership.

Comment: Hmm, so recast in terms of probability this would look like an uncertainty in the probability of yes with P(yes) = 1 - P(no). I guess I could go bayesian and place a distribution on P(yes) in terms of the distance from the point, but this is starting to get quite clever. What sort of score would I apply to this?

Comment: The standard metrics for evaluating a probability prediction are log loss and Brier score. // You can convert the distance to a probability by using a probability model (like logistic regression) of the distances, as is described in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83602/247274) post. Alternatively, you could model the probability values directly by applying a model like logistic regression, rather than a kNN approach that does not give you what you need.